# How to get the value from block B and Block C to Block A in oracle 10g Xe database forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have 3 data blocks display on a single canvas which are namely:

-Payment Block: items are(pay_id, reservation_id and pay_amount)

-Menu Block which is a view having (reservation_id, meal name, totals, and a display item for summing the totals and display in a display item based on menu canvas. (working fine)

-same for Drink Block(working fine)

Note: It works fine all totals are displayed in their respective display item as the display item was added in their respective block (display item was created based on datablock drink and same for menu on datablock menu.)

-Now please help: How can I add those display item values which are on different data block in the main datablock that is add those values(sum them) and show in the payment block at textbox pay_amount.

help me guys badly need your guidance. Thank you for your time and consideration for this question.

[Image for the nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6paZ4.png)

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLnMw.png)

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLnMw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have blocks A_BLOCK, B_BLOCK, C_BLOCK. Blocks B and C have fields showing certain subsums and that part works fine.
If you want to calculate the total amount of those two subsums and display it in the block A then, one of the ways to do it is:

- open property pallete of the total field in block A
- find the **Calculation** section of the pallete end populate the properties:

  - Calculation mode: **formula**
  - Formula:   **:B_BLOCK.B_SUBSUM_FIELD + :C_BLOCK.C_SUBSUM_FIELD**
  - Summary function: None
  - Summarized block: Null
  - Summarized item: Null

This should do the work for you showing total in block A as a result of the given calculation taking values from blocks B and C. Regards...